# How to teach a convolutional neural network to say "no" to unknown images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, ocr, image-recognition

I have the task of character recognition. There is a certain data set. When I submit an input symbol not from this dataset (or a group of characters from the dataset in one image), then the neural network selects the most similar symbol. The network should say that she does not know such a symbol in this case.
May be there is any architecture for this task?

I'm writing in Python 3 using Keras (Tensorlow as backend).

My architecture:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 29, 29, 75)        1275      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 75)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 75)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 100)       120100    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 2, 125)         200125    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 1, 125)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 1, 125)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 125)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 500)               63000     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 500)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 69)                34569
```

Comment: So you want classification with an aditional "background" class that doesn't fit into any other class?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, yes

Comment: While this might also be an issue of architecture, the main challenge is having data for this background class, because it can come in a great variety of forms. What you could do however is introduce a post processing for your output: Take a threshold, lets say 0.6 and say the network predicts class `j` if output_j > 0.6. If no class reaches this threshold, then the prediction is "background". This might take care of multiple characters in one image

Comment: @FlyingTeller, I set the threshold, but sometimes the network gives a very high probability on the wrong symbols (over 0.9)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

1. Use additional images in the dataset, that corresponds to the class 'unknows', you can obtain this by sampling the images of character like looking symbols. Then train the model for 'n+1' classes, where 'n' is the number of classes that you are currently working on.
2. Carefully look at the softmax output and heuristically choose a threshold.